# Decreasing setInterval value after some time or action

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates circle.

Circles appear every 3 seconds, for this I use `setInterval`

```
const rate = 3000;

setInterval(() => {
    i += 1;
    createDiv(`circle${i}`);
}, rate);
```

Such a question, can I make the speed of the appearance of circles gradually increase, let's say every minute the value decreases by 100?

Or is it possible to somehow make several such `setInterval` and change them after some time has passed? Or just change their values?

```js
//create circle

var clickEl = document.getElementById("clicks");

var spawnRadius = document.getElementById("spawnRadius");
var spawnArea = spawnRadius.getBoundingClientRect();
const circleSize = 95; // Including borders

function createDiv(id, color) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', id);
    if (color === undefined) {
        let colors = ['#ebc6df', '#ebc6c9', '#e1c6eb', '#c6c9eb', '#c6e8eb', '#e373fb', '#f787e6', '#cb87f7', '#87a9f7', '#87f7ee'];
        randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        div.style.borderColor = randomColor;
    }
    else {
        div.style.borderColor = color;
    }
    
    // Randomly position circle within spawn area
    div.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (spawnArea.height - circleSize))}px`;
    div.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (spawnArea.width - circleSize))}px`;
    div.classList.add("circle", "animation");

    // Add click handler
    let clicked = false;
    div.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (clicked) { return; } // Only allow one click per circle
        clicked = true;
        
        div.style.animation = 'Animation 200ms linear forwards';
        setTimeout(() => { spawnRadius.removeChild(div); }, 220);
    });
    
    spawnRadius.appendChild(div);
}

let i = 0;

const rate = 3000;

setInterval(() => {
    i += 1;
    createDiv(`circle${i}`);
}, rate);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #0f0f0f;
}

.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
}

#spawnRadius {
    top: 55%;
    height: 650px;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #0f0f0f;
    border: 2px solid #ebc6df;
}

@keyframes Animation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="spawnRadius"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR:* Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) instead of setInterval. That way, on every timeout you can decrement your spawn rate *ms* timeout:

```js
const createCircle = () => { /* Your code goes here */ };

const spawnRate = {curr: 3000, min: 400};

const loop = () => {
  createCircle();
  spawnRate.curr -= 100;
  spawnRate.curr = Math.max(spawnRate.min, spawnRate.curr);
  setTimeout(loop, spawnRate.curr);
};

loop(); // Start loop!
```

- to prevent your loop go to extreme speeds you can also make use of [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)  to limit your spawn rate to a `spawnRate.min`
- you don't need a setTimeout to remove an element after 200ms, use the ["animationend" Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event).
- use [Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) and [Element.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) methods
- You don't need to cancel/prevent extra clicks using variables, just pass the `{once: true}` options to the Event Listener.

Example:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const ELS = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);

// Task: Create circles

const colorRand = () => `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 360)}, 80%, 80%)`;
const EL_spawn = EL("#spawnRadius");

const spawnRate = {
  curr: 3000,
  min: 400,
};

const createCircle = () => {
  
  const BCR_area = EL_spawn.getBoundingClientRect();
  const EL_circle = ELNew("div", {className: `circle animation`});
  const size = 95;

  Object.assign(EL_circle.style, {
    borderColor: colorRand(),
    top: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (BCR_area.height - size))}px`,
    left: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (BCR_area.width - size))}px`,
    width: `${size}px`,
    height: `${size}px`,
  });

  EL_circle.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    EL_circle.style.animation = 'Animation 200ms linear forwards';
    EL_circle.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
      EL_circle.remove();
    });
  }, {once: true});

  EL_spawn.append(EL_circle);
};

const loop = () => {
  createCircle();
  spawnRate.curr -= 100;
  spawnRate.curr = Math.max(spawnRate.min, spawnRate.curr);
  setTimeout(loop, spawnRate.curr);
};

loop(); // Start loop!
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0f0f0f;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.circle:hover {
  background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 100%, 0.1);
}

#spawnRadius {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes Animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="spawnRadius"></div>
```

- you don't necessarily need an Array of colors... you could use [**hsl()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl()) clors for that matter.